# LESS CSS: abusing the & Operator when nesting?

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

Less uses the `&` Operator to enhance the [possibilities for nesting](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-nested-rules).

```
.header        { color: black;
  .navigation  { font-size: 12px;
    &.class    { text-decoration: none }
  }
}
```

which causes a substitution of the `&` with the parent selector and results in a concatentation of the actual selector right to the parent selector: `.header .navigation.class` instead of the normal appending, which would result in `.class` being a decendant: `.header .navigation .class`.

Now what also is possible is the following ([see also here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522508/1047823)):

```
.header        { color: black;
  .navigation  { font-size: 12px;
    #some-id & .foo   { text-decoration: none }
  }
}
```

which would result in the following: `#some-id .header .navigation .foo` [try here](http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) . The substition takes place and i have **prepended** a selector (`#some-id`) to my parent selector.

Besides the fact that I would never code this way, since this probably messes up your stylesheet in no time, my question:

**As this functionality is not documented, is it a feature or more likely a bug?

Which are possible side-effects?**

Comment: Don't understant you, what is the point of "#some-id &"? Surely wrong code can procude wrong compilation/transformation results and it's impossible to document all wrong behavior.

Comment: @DenisAgarev Are you experienced with LESS? If not, just read and don't write please...

Comment: Enough experienced, but forget about this syntax, Sorry. Maybe coding like that is usefull to edit some existing large css file but i think usual use of such substitutions maybe be dangerous

Comment: This is intentional behaviour. Searching through the [less.js](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/tree/master/lib/less) source for `'&'` makes that clear. The LESS documentation is not fantastic, which is the most likely reason for this being undocumented. Possible side-effects include: it can be confusing to use `&` in the middle of a selector.

Comment: Here's the documentation: http://lesscss.org/features/#parent-selectors-feature, weirdly it only mentions prepending :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I also have been pondering this use further since we encountered it [in that question you referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519931/less-css-accessing-classes-further-up-the-dom-tree-from-within-a-nested-class/11522508#11522508). While I cannot answer definitively that this is a "bug" use  for `&` (BoltClock seems to make a good argument that it is *not* a bug), I want to argue for the value of it (which argues it is not a bug from a logical standpoint).

However, before the logical argument, I did find [another short, simple quote](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/wiki) (in the "nested rules" section) that seems to indicate it is at least not unintended: "`&` represents the current selector parent." That's it. As BoltClock argues, whether prepending or appending seems irrelevant. All that was intended was that it be a placeholder for that "selector parent" that is current up to that point. The fact that it is always mentioned in conjunction with the "nesting" use of the language implies it is designed to designate the full selector string of the nest up to the point of the nest that it resides within. How that string is used (to pre- or append) would seem up to the coder.

Now, you mention (and previously mentioned) that you "would never code this way," and yet I find myself seeing what appears to be a very valuable use for this. Consider the following argument.

### The HTML Setup for the Illustration

Assume, for the sake of illustration, there is a dynamic setting of three possible classes ('light', 'medium', 'dark' themes) on the `body` element that change the "look" of the site. We have 
two columns, and some various types of links we want to style (`textLink`, `picLink`, `textWithIconLink`) differently in each column for each theme.

```html
<body class="light">
  <div class="leftCol">
     <a class="textLink"></a>
     <a class="picLink"></a>
     <a class="textWithIconLink"></a>
  </div>
  <div class="rightCol">
     <a class="textLink"></a>
     <a class="picLink"></a>
     <a class="textWithIconLink"></a>
  </div>
</body>
```

***Now the questions to ask are, just looking at the links, of the two following methods, which...***

1. Is less code in LESS
2. Best organzies the code in LESS
3. Outputs less code in CSS
4. Best organizes the outputted CSS

"Best" may be somewhat subjective. I'll let you weigh that evidence yourself from below.

### Option #1 Typical Nesting

**LESS** (approx. 99 lines of code)

```css
/*Light Color Theme */
    .light {
      .leftCol {
        .textLink {
          color: fooL1;
          &:hover { color: barL1;}
        } 
        .picLink {
          background-image: url(/fooL1.jpg);
          &:hover { background-image: url(/barL1.jpg);}
        }
        .textWithIconLink {
          color: fooL2;
          background-image: url(/fooL2.jpg);
          &:hover { color: barL2; background-image: url(/barL2.jpg);}
        }   
      }
      .rightCol {
        .textLink {
          color: fooL3;
          &:hover { color: barL3;}
        } 
        .picLink {
          background-image: url(/fooL3.jpg);
          &:hover { background-image: url(/barL3.jpg);}
        }
        .textWithIconLink {
          color: fooL4;
          background-image: url(/fooL4.jpg);
          &:hover { color: barL4; background-image: url(/barL4.jpg);}
        }   
      }
    }
/*Medium Color Theme */
    .medium {
      .leftCol {
        .textLink {
          color: fooM1;
          &:hover { color: barM1;}
        } 
        .picLink {
          background-image: url(/fooM1.jpg);
          &:hover { background-image: url(/barM1.jpg);}
        }
        .textWithIconLink {
          color: fooM2;
          background-image: url(/fooM2.jpg);
          &:hover { color: barM2; background-image: url(/barM2.jpg);}
        }   
      }
      .rightCol {
        .textLink {
          color: fooM3;
          &:hover { color: barM3;}
        } 
        .picLink {
          background-image: url(/fooM3.jpg);
          &:hover { background-image: url(/barM3.jpg);}
        }
        .textWithIconLink {
          color: fooM4;
          background-image: url(/fooM4.jpg);
          &:hover { color: barM4; background-image: url(/barM4.jpg);}
        }   
      }
    }
/*Dark Color Theme */
    .dark {
      .leftCol {
        .textLink {
          color: fooD1;
          &:hover { color: barD1;}
        } 
        .picLink {
          background-image: url(/fooD1.jpg);
          &:hover { background-image: url(/barD1.jpg);}
        }
        .textWithIconLink {
          color: fooD2;
          background-image: url(/fooD2.jpg);
          &:hover { color: barD2; background-image: url(/barD2.jpg);}
        }   
      }
      .rightCol {
        .textLink {
          color: fooD3;
          &:hover { color: barD3;}
        } 
        .picLink {
          background-image: url(/fooD3.jpg);
          &:hover { background-image: url(/barD3.jpg);}
        }
        .textWithIconLink {
          color: fooD4;
          background-image: url(/fooD4.jpg);
          &:hover { color: barD4; background-image: url(/barD4.jpg);}
        }   
      }
    }
```

**CSS Output** (approx. 87 lines of output, organized by theme of course)

```css
 /*Light Color Theme */
.light .leftCol .textLink { color:fooL1; }
.light .leftCol .textLink:hover { color:barL1; }
.light .leftCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooL1.jpg); }
.light .leftCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barL1.jpg); }
.light .leftCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooL2;
  background-image:url(/fooL2.jpg);
}
.light .leftCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barL2;
  background-image:url(/barL2.jpg);
}
.light .rightCol .textLink { color:fooL3; }
.light .rightCol .textLink:hover { color:barL3; }
.light .rightCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooL3.jpg); }
.light .rightCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barL3.jpg); }
.light .rightCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooL4;
  background-image:url(/fooL4.jpg);
}
.light .rightCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barL4;
  background-image:url(/barL4.jpg);
}
/*Medium Color Theme */
.medium .leftCol .textLink { color:fooM1; }
.medium .leftCol .textLink:hover { color:barM1; }
.medium .leftCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooM1.jpg); }
.medium .leftCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barM1.jpg); }
.medium .leftCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooM2;
  background-image:url(/fooM2.jpg);
}
.medium .leftCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barM2;
  background-image:url(/barM2.jpg);
}
.medium .rightCol .textLink { color:fooM3; }
.medium .rightCol .textLink:hover { color:barM3; }
.medium .rightCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooM3.jpg); }
.medium .rightCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barM3.jpg); }
.medium .rightCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooM4;
  background-image:url(/fooM4.jpg);
}
.medium .rightCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barM4;
  background-image:url(/barM4.jpg);
}
/*Dark Color Theme */
.dark .leftCol .textLink { color:fooD1; }
.dark .leftCol .textLink:hover { color:barD1; }
.dark .leftCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooD1.jpg); }
.dark .leftCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barD1.jpg); }
.dark .leftCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooD2;
  background-image:url(/fooD2.jpg);
}
.dark .leftCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barD2;
  background-image:url(/barD2.jpg);
}
.dark .rightCol .textLink { color:fooD3; }
.dark .rightCol .textLink:hover { color:barD3; }
.dark .rightCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooD3.jpg); }
.dark .rightCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barD3.jpg); }
.dark .rightCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooD4;
  background-image:url(/fooD4.jpg);
}
.dark .rightCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barD4;
  background-image:url(/barD4.jpg);
}
```

### Option #2 End Target Grouping

I've named it "End Target Grouping," because that's really how I see using the `&` in this other way of adding parent selectors. One is now coding based off the final end target element that is actually being styled.

**LESS** (approx. 88 lines of code)

```css
/*Links */
/*Text  Links*/
.textLink {
  .light .leftCol &  {
      color: fooL1;
      &:hover { color: barL1;}
    }      
  .light .rightCol &  {
      color: fooL3;
      &:hover { color: barL3;}
    } 
  .medium .leftCol &  {
      color: fooM1;
      &:hover { color: barM1;}
    } 
  .medium .rightCol &  {
      color: fooM3;
      &:hover { color: barM3;}
    } 
  .dark .leftCol &  {
      color: fooD1;
      &:hover { color: barD1;}
    } 
  .dark .rightCol &  {
      color: fooD3;
      &:hover { color: barD3;}
    } 
}
/*Picture Links */
.picLink {
  .light .leftCol &  {
      background-image: url(/fooL1.jpg);
      &:hover { background-image: url(/barL1.jpg);}
    } 
  .light .rightCol &  {
      background-image: url(/fooL3.jpg);
      &:hover { background-image: url(/barL3.jpg);}
    } 
  .medium .leftCol &  {
      background-image: url(/fooM1.jpg);
      &:hover { background-image: url(/barM1.jpg);}
    } 
  .medium .rightCol &  {
      background-image: url(/fooM3.jpg);
      &:hover { background-image: url(/barM3.jpg);}
    } 
  .dark .leftCol &  {
      background-image: url(/fooD1.jpg);
      &:hover { background-image: url(/barD1.jpg);}
    } 
  .dark .rightCol &  {
      background-image: url(/fooD3.jpg);
      &:hover { background-image: url(/barD3.jpg);}
    } 
}
/*Text with Icon Links */
.textWithIconLink {
  .light .leftCol &  {
      color: fooL2;
      background-image: url(/fooL1.jpg);
      &:hover { color: barL2; background-image: url(/barL1.jpg);}
    } 
  .light .rightCol &  {
      color: fooL4;
      background-image: url(/fooL3.jpg);
      &:hover { color: barL4;  background-image: url(/barL3.jpg);}
    } 
  .medium .leftCol &  {
      color: fooM2;
      background-image: url(/fooM1.jpg);
      &:hover { color: barM2; background-image: url(/barM1.jpg);}
    } 
  .medium .rightCol &  {
     color: fooM4;
      background-image: url(/fooM3.jpg);
      &:hover { color: barM4; background-image: url(/barM3.jpg);}
    } 
  .dark .leftCol &  {
     color: fooD2;
      background-image: url(/fooD1.jpg);
      &:hover { color: barD2; background-image: url(/barD1.jpg);}
    } 
  .dark .rightCol &  {
      color: fooD4;
      background-image: url(/fooD3.jpg);
      &:hover { color: barD4; background-image: url(/barD3.jpg);}
    } 
}
```

**CSS** (approx. 88 lines of output [due to one extra comment], organized by end target element; but notice, there is still a suborganization by theme because of the class structure)

```css
/*Links*/
/*Text  Links*/
.light .leftCol .textLink { color:fooL1; }
.light .leftCol .textLink:hover { color:barL1; }
.light .rightCol .textLink { color:fooL3; }
.light .rightCol .textLink:hover { color:barL3; }
.medium .leftCol .textLink { color:fooM1; }
.medium .leftCol .textLink:hover { color:barM1; }
.medium .rightCol .textLink { color:fooM3; }
.medium .rightCol .textLink:hover { color:barM3; }
.dark .leftCol .textLink { color:fooD1; }
.dark .leftCol .textLink:hover { color:barD1; }
.dark .rightCol .textLink { color:fooD3; }
.dark .rightCol .textLink:hover { color:barD3; }
/*Picture Links */
.light .leftCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooL1.jpg); }
.light .leftCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barL1.jpg); }
.light .rightCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooL3.jpg); }
.light .rightCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barL3.jpg); }
.medium .leftCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooM1.jpg); }
.medium .leftCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barM1.jpg); }
.medium .rightCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooM3.jpg); }
.medium .rightCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barM3.jpg); }
.dark .leftCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooD1.jpg); }
.dark .leftCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barD1.jpg); }
.dark .rightCol .picLink { background-image:url(/fooD3.jpg); }
.dark .rightCol .picLink:hover { background-image:url(/barD3.jpg); }
/*Text with Icon Links */
.light .leftCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooL2;
  background-image:url(/fooL1.jpg);
}
.light .leftCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barL2;
  background-image:url(/barL1.jpg);
}
.light .rightCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooL4;
  background-image:url(/fooL3.jpg);
}
.light .rightCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barL4;
  background-image:url(/barL3.jpg);
}
.medium .leftCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooM2;
  background-image:url(/fooM1.jpg);
}
.medium .leftCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barM2;
  background-image:url(/barM1.jpg);
}
.medium .rightCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooM4;
  background-image:url(/fooM3.jpg);
}
.medium .rightCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barM4;
  background-image:url(/barM3.jpg);
}
.dark .leftCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooD2;
  background-image:url(/fooD1.jpg);
}
.dark .leftCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barD2;
  background-image:url(/barD1.jpg);
}
.dark .rightCol .textWithIconLink {
  color:fooD4;
  background-image:url(/fooD3.jpg);
}
.dark .rightCol .textWithIconLink:hover {
  color:barD4;
  background-image:url(/barD3.jpg);
}
```

### Concluding Thoughts

A few other considerations:

First, most of your theme colors (and possibly other themeing aspects) will be set up with variables, which can be grouped at the top of the LESS code by theme even using Option #2 above--so having the theme structure for the output CSS itself scattered in the code is not necessarily bad.

Second, any "standard" code for a type of element is defined above any theme code. My examples did not show this, but say all `.textLink` elements had `text-decoration: none;` set. That would occur once under Option #2 without any further selector code, and would appear above all the theme changes below. For Option #1, I need to set up a new, *unnested* `.textLink` selector (at least one other line of code) to apply it to all themed links, and that "base" code for the class will, again, be somewhere unrelated to where the rest of the code for the theme link info is.

Third, as a developer, if I am having issues with my `picLinks` (a specific type of element on my page), Option #2 makes it far easier to examine my code for the element I am having issues with, as all my code for all the themes is right in one spot.

***Obviously, how one wants the final LESS and CSS organized is going to be a major factor in how one sees the value of this.*** My point here is to merely demonstrate that there is a very useful, logical reason to use the `&` in this way of adding parent level selectors to the `&` reference.

Comment: Ahhh... "placeholder" was the very word that was eluding me. (I had actually written that answer on my iPhone at a time when I couldn't really concentrate... I'm better now though of course!)

Comment: @BoltClock--Glad I could read your subliminal thoughts. Now if I could just pick up on the rest of your css knowledge...

Comment: Thank you for your detailed post. I really appreciated it. Yet i want to explain my statement "would never code this way". Just imagine a 500-1000 line less file. Should be no problem with huge projects. Now you want to debug your css - it's minified. Without this "abusive" usage the selector `#test .foo .bar .hello` could have only one place due to the limitation of the nesting. With this "abusive" use, you can't determine in which nesting level to look for the rule as the css-selector could be located everywhere.

Comment: @Christoph--First, I don't try to debug minified code, but source code. But I grant that is not always possible. However, second, if used as I have shown, there is still only "one place" your selector path would be: under the `.hello` "end target" section of code. In other words, my proposed use is sort of a reversed nest. All code affecting directly the `.hello` is together. I think where trouble could come in is if one uses the `&` at some midpoint. So `#test .foo [& = .bar] .hello` where you now are adding _both_ parents and children together.

Answer (score 6):

It's not abuse of the `&` combinator at all; you can place it *anywhere* in a nested selector and it'll be substituted with whatever is above it (its so-called parent selector):

> [The `&` combinator is] used when you want a nested selector to be concatenated to its parent selector, instead of acting as a descendant.

Notice that it says "concatenated"; it doesn't say you can only either prepend or append the parent selector to the nested selector. Concatenation doesn't work in any specific direction only.

Further, the word "descendant" has to do with the nature of nested selectors being treated as though they were linked by the descendant combinator by default. In no way does that inherently limit the use of `&` to descendants only, nor does it imply that the parent selector has to represent a parent or ancestor element in such a way that the nested selector may only be appended to it, and not prepended or even inserted into the middle of it.

Comment: I know **how** this works and why (that it's a simple substitution), but I wonder if this was intended or not and how far this makes sense or not. It's a rather theoretical question.

Comment: If it wasn't intended, the documentation would likely have said so. It's very clear here that it's intended functionality.

Comment: Well I think you don't get my point... The doc states, that this is used to concatenate additional classes, pseudo-elements/-classes to the recent selector. However, it is not documented to be used for prepending additional selectors at the beginning of the path somewhere in the nesting tree.

Comment: It doesn't say you can only append the selector. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Read my edit again, especially the paragraph just beneath the quote which I added along with it.