# How to specify a html tag on a LESS CSS nested class?

Tags: css, less

I have a class used on an `article` and a `section` HTML5 tag.

On the home:

```
<article class="exit">
    <a href="exit.php">
        <figure class="box">
            <img src="assets/img/projects/exit-m.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption>…</figcaption>
        </figure>
    </a>
</article>
```

On the project page:

```
<section class="page project exit">
    <div class="corner nw intro">
        <figure class="box">
            <img src="assets/img/projects/exit.jpg" alt="">
            <figcaption>…</figcaption>
        </figure>
   </div>
   …
```

Each elements with the class **exit** have a `figure` HTML5 element inside. With Less, I use this code to do what I want.

```
article.exit{width:260px; height:200px; top:315px; left:505px;
    figure{background-color:@exit-bg;}
    .box:hover{.perspective-box(se, 10, @exit-shadow);}
}
section.exit{
    .box:hover{.perspective-box(nw, 10, @exit-shadow);}
    .intro figcaption:hover{background:@exit-hover;}
}
```

But I have to specify if it's an `article` or a `section`! I have a lot of classes like that and it's a little annoying…

Is there a solution to do something like this? It will be very cool…

```
.exit{
    &article{
        width:260px; height:200px; top:315px; left:505px;
        figure{background-color:@exit-bg;}
        .box:hover{.perspective-box(se, 10, @exit-shadow);}
    }
    &section{
        .box:hover{.perspective-box(nw, 10, @exit-shadow);}
        .intro figcaption:hover{background:@exit-hover;}
    }
}
```

Comment: CSS does not support nesting like. It would be oh-so-very-handy if it did, but the W3C is not about making life easy for people.

Comment: Yep but I use LESS CSS, it accepts this nesting… maybe not what I search, but it works.

http://lesscss.org/#-nested-rules

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I kinda don't see much of a point in trying to nest these two rules if they won't share any common styles within the `exit` class.

That said, if you still want to nest them, remember that in selectors, element names always precede other simple selectors. Try placing the `&` after the element name and see if it works:

```
.exit{
    article&{
        width:260px; height:200px; top:315px; left:505px;
        figure{background-color:@exit-bg;}
        .box:hover{.perspective-box(se, 10, @exit-shadow);}
    }
    section&{
        .box:hover{.perspective-box(nw, 10, @exit-shadow);}
        .intro figcaption:hover{background:@exit-hover;}
    }
}
```

Comment: haha, seriously? I'll just have to reverse? ok… it works. Thank you!
And I use this nested class to avoid a repetition of the class. It's more efficient for futures classes names changes!

Comment: Nice, didn't know this was possible.

Comment: Hehe, that's some nice usecase for our little discussion we had, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537260/less-css-abusing-the-operator-when-nesting ;)

Comment: @Christoph: :) Just to be clear, `&article` and `&section` doesn't work here not because LESS doesn't allow it, but because it doesn't work as expected in CSS.

Comment: it works if you want to have rules for an element with the class `.exitarticle` :-D

Comment: @Christoph: That's also true.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same doubt and landed here but found an interesting quirk that might be helpful. I prefer to nest the styles according to the HTML that I have written when I am using LESS.

So for example, if my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
  .....
  <div class="form-container">
    <input type="text" class="form-control"....>
    <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
    ......
  </diV
</div>
```

My stylesheet would look like this:

```
#content{
  .form-container{
     color: red;
     .form-control{
       border: 1px solid black;
     }
  }
}
```

Now, I wanted to code the input element and textarea differently. When I looked at the above answer, I tried this:

```
#content{
  .form-container{
     color: red;
     .form-control{
       border: 1px solid black;
       input&{
         height: 40px;
       }
       textarea&{
         height: 100px;
       }
     }
  }
}
```

The `input&` portion (and `textarea&`) was compiled as:

```
input#content .form-container .form-control {
  height: 20px;
}
```

So this is a caveat to keep in mind. To resolve this, just extract the .form-control portion out of the nested portion.