# Apply a tag selector to the immediate parent of a rule within a deeply-nested structure

Tags: css, less

There are a couple of similar questions I've found (like [How to specify a html tag on a LESS CSS nested class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557718/how-to-specify-a-html-tag-on-a-less-css-nested-class)), but none of them seem to work for rules nested more than one level deep.

Here's the structure I have:

```css
article {
  .foo {
    ...
  }
}
```

Here, `.foo` can be one of many different types of element. For the sake of this question, lets say that one of these elements is the `a` element. I'm wanting to extend the above structure to select the `.foo` element whose tag is specifically *`a`* from within the `.foo` rule.

The problem with the answer on the question I've linked to above, and the various other similar questions, is that the following will not work:

```css
article {
  .foo {
    a& { ... }
  }
}
```

Instead of prefixing the `.foo` with the `a` tag, like this:

```css
article a.foo { ... }
```

...the entire chain gets prefixed:

```css
aarticle .foo { ... }
```

([Here's a live example](http://less2css.org/#%7B%22less%22%3A%22article%20%7B%5Cn%20%20.foo%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20a%26%20%7B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%5Ctcolor%3A%20tomato%3B%5Cn%20%20%20%20%7D%5Cn%20%20%7D%5Cn%7D%22%7D)).

How can I target `.foo` elements whose tag is `a` within the `.foo` rule?

Comment: Not possible in Less as far as I know. There is no way to select only the immediate parent (or) part of the parent. Parent selector means the entire parent right upto the root. Maybe you could remove the `article` parent and then attach it to the inner selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're getting tangled up in wanting über-optimized LESS. If I understand correctly, either way your compiled CSS will be

```
article .foo {
    general `article .foo` styles
}
article a.foo {
    additional styles specific to `article a.foo`
}
```

In LESS you could write that as is, or you could do

```
article {
    .foo {
        general `article .foo` styles
    }
    a.foo {
        additional styles specific to `article a.foo`
    }
}
```

or depending on your styles you might be able to do

```
article .foo {
    general `article .foo` styles
}
a.foo {
    additional styles specific to `a.foo`
}
```