# LESS nesting styles to mimic html layout?

Tags: css, less

This nested mess is what the layout of my less stylesheet looks like (minus any actual styles):

```
#branding {
    h1 {

    }
    #tagline {

    }
    .ticker {

    }
    nav {
        ul {
            li {
                a {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    #search-form {
        input {

        }
        button {

        }
    }
}
#masthead {
    #store-locator {

    }
    #slider {
        ul {
            li {

            }
        }
    }
    #events {
        article {
            img {

            }
            h4 {

            }
            p {

            }
        }
    }
}
#main {
    #buckets {
        ul {
            li {
                img {

                }
                h3 {

                }
                .description {
                    .author {
                        a {

                        }
                    }
                    p {

                    }
                    blockquote {

                    }
                }
                .more {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    #social-feed {
        hgroup {

        }
        #filters {
            ul {
                li {

                }
            }
        }
        #feeds {
            .feed-column {
                > div {
                    img {

                    }
                    h3 {
                        span {

                        }
                    }
                    .description {
                        p {

                        }
                        .author {
                            a {

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        #feed-amount {
            a {
                &:before {

                }
                &:after {

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
#summary {
    nav {
        ul {
            li {
                a {

                }
            }
        }
    }
    #newsletter-form {
        h4 {

        }
        input {

        }
        button {

        }
    }
    #stay-connected {
        h4 {
            a {

            }
        }
    }
    #donation {

    }
    #contact-info {
        #contact-number {
            span {
                strong {

                }
            }
        }
        #contact-details {
            address {
                strong {
                    a {

                    }
                }
            }
            p {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

This makes sense to me in some ways because it mimics the layout of the markup, but it has some serious drawbacks such as overly specific selectors, IE:

```
#main #social-feed #feeds .feed-column > div .description p {}
```

My question is, what would be a better way to lay this document out?

Am I abusing LESS here? I searched "LESS stylesheet examples" and similar things, but I could not find one single example of a less stylesheet in its entirety--can anyone provide me of an example of a well-crafted less document?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selector bloating like you illustrate as one of the "serious drawbacks" is why I would use nesting of selectors sparingly. For me, having the CSS *exactly* match the layout of the markup is not that significant. I can use a few sparse comments to help me know what "section" I'm in in the CSS. So let me walk through some thoughts about how I might change things.

### Keep Near, not Necessarily Nested

**Example**

```
/* branding */

#branding {
    h1 { }

    .ticker { }

    nav {
        ul { }
        li { }
        a { }
    }
}

#tagline { }

#search-form {
    input { }
    button { }
}
```

**Discussion**

First, note how put a comment as my section heading, rather than just using the `#branding` to group everything. This is my keeping of some "structure" like the html, I group by major "wrapper" headings and keep them near each other.

Second, any `id` tag's should be there own top level nesting group, assuming that you *are correctly structuring your html* to keep id's unique to a page. The only exception in my mind would be if you are using some class on the `body` element to switch looks on pages, and part of that look change includes a change to styling on an element selected by `id` (but even that may be handled by still putting `id` as top level; see "Utilize the Power of `&`" below). So I have pulled out your `#tagline` and `#search-form` from the nest under `#branding`.

Third, think about your design and code for minimal bloat. For example, if you have other `nav` elements on page (sub navs in side bars, etc.), then nesting the `nav` in `#branding` is worthwhile. Likewise, if you have other `h1` or `.ticker` uses outside that wrapper. However, a common nest that I despise is the `ul li a` nest. If the only list inside `nav` is the `ul`, then there is no reason to nest the `li` inside it and end up with `ul li` in your selector string, because it is a given that all the `li` are located there. Likewise, if the only `a` tags in the `nav` are inside the list, then no need to nest that. Having this css...

```
#branding nav ul { }
#branding nav li { }
#branding nav a { }
```

...is just as clean and far less bloated in its selector string than the full nest version.

### Utilize the power of &

[I like the idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537260/less-css-abusing-the-operator-when-nesting/11544805#11544805) of using the `&` to add key parents to code. Recall the exception above about adding a class on the `body` element to control theming (or looks) across pages. You could nest it in the theme class, or you could do this:

**Example**

```
#branding {
    .theme1 & { }
    .theme2 & { }

    h1 { }

    .ticker { }

    nav {
        ul { }
        li { }
        a { }
    }
}
```

**Discussion**

Which would then produce a selector like `.theme1 #branding` to change the look of the `#branding` by the theme class. If you needed this to change properties for the items nested in it, there are various ways you can do it (it depends so much on what structure you want your final output to look like). One way is add it only to what is needed:

**Example**

```
#branding {
    .theme1 & { }
    .theme2 & { }

    h1 { 
      .theme2 & { //special code only for theme2 here }
    }

    .ticker { }

    nav {
        ul { 
          //main code here
          .theme1 & { //special code here }
          .theme2 & { }
        }
        li { }
        a { }
    }
}
```

**Discussion**

The *disadvantage* is some extra repetition of `.theme` classes in the code, while the *advantage* to this is that it keeps the *end point* targets grouped, so for example the `ul` above would produce code like this...

```
#branding nav ul {}
.theme1 #branding nav ul {}
.theme2 #branding nav ul {} 
#branding nav li {}
#branding nav a {}
```

...which keeps the all the various `ul` code next to each other. Now, if the `li` and `a` elements also needed changing on theme, you would have to decide if you want to move the themeing up a level so that the `ul`, `li` and `a` for a particular theme are grouped next to each other *by theme*, or if you keep it at the lowest level like above so that each `ul`, `li`, and `a` stay grouped *by endpoint tag* that is actually being styled.

Of course, using `&` to append normally is still useful in nesting, so...

```
a {
  &:hover {}
}
```

...to produce the `a:hover {}` info no matter how deeply nested the `a` may be is a great use of nesting and `&` combined.

### Conclusion

There is certainly more that could be said on the subject. The key is to utilize the power of preprocessors where it is needed, not just because it is available. For me, mixins are the more useful part of preprocessors as opposed to nesting.

Comment: Very thorough, educational answer. That makes sense that IDs don't to be nested, and I didn't even know about using the `&` in that way to target the parent. Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me, I hope it helps others too

Answer (score 2):

If LESS *allows* to nest selectors, then it does not mean that you necessarily *should* do that. Just do same things as you would do with regular CSS.

If your purpose is just visual hierarchy, then you can do this without real nesting:

```
#social-feed {
    /**/
}
    #feeds {
        /**/
    }
```

It typically does not make sense to nest id selectors (like `#foo #bar`) (as long as your elements hierarchy is persistent across different pages).

Also, it makes sense to use child combinator when it's applicable:

```
nav {
    & > ul {
        & > li {
            & > a {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

sothat resulting selector (`NAV > UL > LI > A`) could work potentially faster than a context selector (`NAV UL LI A` or `NAV A`).

Comment: I agree, great point on the visual hierarchy without nesting. The resulting CSS can now be the same as if I had hand-typed it, which wouldn't have been the case with nesting