# Less immediate parent selector without root selector

Tags: less

This LESS:

```
.parent {
  .child {
    h1& {
      color: red;
    }
  } 
}
```

Compiles to:

`h1.parent .child {color:red};`

What I need is:

`.parent h1.child {color:red};`

Suggestion appreciated.

My question is similar to the question [Less Immediate Parent Selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21985161/less-immediate-parent-selector) but not quite the same. As the selector is composed from the element and class name. The question is about how to qualify the class name with its element without affecting the root selector.

Answer (score 0):

This will work for this specific example. Although I appreciate it doesn't answer your general question.

```
.parent {
   h1 {
    &.child {
      color: red;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: Also have a look at the "extend" feature added in less v1.4 -- http://lesscss.org/features/#extend-feature

Comment: This has nothing to do whit the question.