# Overriding nesting, to stay in scope

Tags: css, less

I was wondering if I could override the nesting in LESS, to stay in my scope - just because it's simpler... :-)

If I have an element which has two states, depending on let's say a `body`-class, I need to define two CSS objects. I would like to have only one, per module.

```
.module {
    h1 {
        float: left;
    }
}

body.secondary {
    .module {
        h1 {
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

Like when you define the parent with `&`, is there any way to overwrite that parent?? So maybe it could look like this:

```
.module {
    h1 {
        float: left;
    }

    &=body.secondary {
        h1 {
            float: right;
        }
    }
}
```

Where the `&` is defined as another selector...

This could be awesome, and make my CSS more simple in terms of one CSS object per module.

Thanks... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done some extensive commentary on this both in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11537260/less-css-abusing-the-operator-when-nesting/11544805#11544805) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519931/less-css-accessing-classes-further-up-the-dom-tree-from-within-a-nested-class/11522508#11522508). In your particular case, it would be this:

**LESS**

```
.module {
    h1 {
        float: left;
       body.secondary & {
          float: right;
       }  
    }
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
.module h1 {
  float: left;
}
body.secondary .module h1 {
  float: right;
}
```

The key is to realize that the `&` is not just for targeting the "parent" per se in the html structure, but rather is a string replacement for the entire nested structure it sits within. So in my solution above, the nested LESS "parent" is `.module h1` which is the string replaced at the `&` point in the `body.secondary &` construct nested within it.